# Unable to load picture or PDF XeLaTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex

I have a problem when including an image under XeLaTeX :

```
>! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'cachan.jpg'.<to be read again>\GXT@clipend \Garde
```

I tried everything and nothing works. I changed the name of my image, I change the format...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my complete MWE (I compile in the main document):

---

```
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand{\Garde}{
  \begin{titlepage}
 \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{cachan.jpg}     
\hfill 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{saclay} 
     \hfill
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{paris1} 
     \hfill

    \vspace{2cm}
      {\Large\textsc{Mémoire de première année de Master}}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
      {\large\textsc{Mention \enquote{Histoire contemporaine}}}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
      {\large\textsc{Année universitaire} 2015 -- 2016}\\
    \vspace{2.5cm}
      {\Huge {\bfseries Ceci est le titre}}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
        {\Large Ceci est le sous-titre de mon mémoire qui est un peu plus long que le titre}\\
    \vspace{2.5cm}
        \textit{présenté et soutenu par}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
        {\Large \@author} \\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
        le 5 juin 2016 \\
  \vspace{2cm}
        \textit{sous la direction d'}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
        {\Large Olivier \textsc{Wieviorka}} \\
  \end{titlepage}

}
```

[Copied from answer by cfr]

Thank you to helphing so fast !

Here is my complete MWE (I apologize for my mistakes and my bad english..)

It's quite long :

==============

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\input{Preambule/Preambule}
%\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=verbose-trad2, bibstyle=verbose]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{fiches.bib}

\author{XXX \textsc{XXX}}

\include{Page_de_garde/Page_de_garde}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\Garde

\setcounter{page}{1}    

\thispagestyle{plain}
\include{Remerciements/Remerciements}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\mainmatter
\include{Chapitre_1/Chapitre_1}

\appendix 
\backmatter 

\end{document}
```

---

```
Preambule

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{appendix}
\AddThinSpaceBeforeFootnotes
\FrenchFootnotes
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\small{page {\thepage} sur \pageref{LastPage}}} 
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textsc{\small{XXX}}} 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}              
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
   \appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{{\textsc{Tableau}}}}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\BR@backref}{\newblock}{\newblock(page~}{}{}  
\patchcmd{\BR@backref}{\par}{)\par}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{array}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0023}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0024}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0028}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0030}   
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter \@removefromreset{figure}{chapter}\makeatother
\makeatletter \@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}\makeatother
\makeatletter \@removefromreset{footcite}{chapter}\makeatother
\makeatletter \@removefromreset{table}{chapter}\makeatother
```

---

```
% Page_de_garde
\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\Garde}{
  \begin{titlepage}
 \centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{cachan.jpg}     
\hfill 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{saclay} 
 \hfill
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{paris1} 
 \hfill

\vspace{2cm}
  {\Large\textsc{Mémoire de première année de Master}}\\
\vspace{0.3cm}
  {\large\textsc{Mention \enquote{Histoire contemporaine}}}\\
\vspace{0.3cm}
  {\large\textsc{Année universitaire} 2015 -- 2016}\\
\vspace{2.5cm}
  {\Huge {\bfseries Ceci est le titre}}\\
\vspace{0.3cm}
    {\Large Ceci est le sous-titre de mon mémoire}\\
\vspace{2.5cm}
    \textit{présenté et soutenu par}\\
\vspace{0.3cm}
    {\Large \@author} \\
\vspace{0.3cm}
    le 5 juin 2016 \\
  \vspace{2cm}
    \textit{sous la direction d'}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    {\Large Olivier \textsc{Wieviorka}} \\
  \end{titlepage}

    }
```

Comment: I fear this is NOT a complete mwe. Your document lacks a preamble, which, I assume, is in the "main document". We can only guess what do you mean by "trying everything".

Comment: It probably has to do with the use of sub-directories. You are loading something from a sub-directory which then tries to load an image which... It can't find the image file is the problem.

Comment: `\include{}` should be used for things like complete chapters. It shouldn't be used for further parts of your preamble. And you should not have formatting markup in the argument of a command such as `\author{}`. If it should be small-cap, you should set things up so that the author is small-capped when used in creating the title etc.

Comment: Also, since you have posted so much code, you really need to tidy this up. You are using deprecated, obsolete and simply incompatible packages. You absolutely ought not load **inputenc** if using XeTeX and almost certainly ought not use **fontenc** either unless you absolutely know why you are doing so and what you are doing. You definitely ought not be loading **ae** or **lmodern**. I don't know what **aecompl** is, but I'm guessing that should go too. Don't load **enumerate** if using **enumitem**. You must get many warnings and bad boxes.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I will tidy this now. I am a beginer, so I don't understand everything and I do a lot ok mistakes !

Comment: Do you want me to change my post ? What I am supposed to do ? I am really sorry if I am not clear or if I don't respect the rules of this forum.

Comment: Finally, it works. I had to move the images in a other directorie. Now, I have to learn how ton clean my code and how to solve all the warnings and bad boxes..!